# Why is my variable coming back as undefined?

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with my script? It has a global variable which is later set with a function, but it comes back as undefined. Why is that?

```
<script>
var userName

function getAnonUserName() {
  $.ajax({
  url: "https://ck:8081/get-username",
  type: "get",
  success: function(response) {
  userName = response
  }
  })
}

window.onload = function() {
 getAnonUserName()
 console.log(userName)
```

Comment: `$.ajax` is asynchronous, so your `console.log()` is called earlier than you get it.

Comment: function getAnonUserName() {
  $.ajax({
  url: "https://ck:8081/get-username",
  type: "get",
  success: function(response) {
  userName = response
  }
  }).done(function(){console.log(userName)}) // try this it will print
}

Answer (score -1):

getAnonUserName is asynchronous, you have to wait for the response